# Using helpers with grunt-static-handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, handlebars.js

Can anyone give me any pointers/examples on how to use your own custom helpers with [grunt-static-handlebars](https://github.com/Techtribe/grunt-static-handlebars)? I've read the documentation and can't see how to do this.

I created helpers to use when using handlebars client side and I'd love to be able to replicate that on the serverside when building pages but currently can't work out how to do that.

I tried to create the fullName helper from the handlebars docs. I set my helpersPath to */helpers* and created a fullName.js with this code

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('fullName', function(person) {
    return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
});
```

Then I added it to the *base.json* config file

```
{
    ...
    "helpers": [
        "fullName"
    ],
    ...
}
```

And then attempt to use it in a partial *{{fullName person}}*

But when I attempt to run the grunt task I getting an error. `Fatal error: Object #<Object> has no method 'call'`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [grunt-handlebars-to-static](https://github.com/xbtsw/grunt-handlebars-to-static), which have a [example project](https://github.com/xbtsw/grunt-handlebars-to-static/tree/master/examples/global_setup) available solving your exact problem. Also the task is highly flexible for all different kinds of folder arrangement. The docs gives two examples of most typical folder arrangement as starters.

*Disclaimer: I am the author :) Cheers.*